# I ended up eating my cat. Can I get a new one?

Tags: sheltered

Due to an early-game resource squeeze, my cat ended up starving to death, and was promptly eaten, much to the horror of the shelter dwellers.

Having since secured my shelter better in terms of resources, I am now at a point where I'd like to have a cat once more; is there any way to obtain one?

(Or, failing that, some other pet.)

Comment: Upvoted for the awesome title, which makes me want to go play this game.

Comment: Why would a mouse want a cat as pet?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Chinchilla.

Comment: I'm hoping this shows up under the Hot Network Questions and people confuse it for a question on pets.stackexchange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no way to get another pet, but Sonny Meek, co-owners with Dean Foster at Unicube, mentioned [on their forums on March 8th](http://www.unicube.net/discussion-forum/topic/finding-new-pets/) that they plan to add this feature in a future update.

Actual quote from Sonny after a user suggested new pets, and possible ways and locations to get them.

> *Sonny*:
>
> [...] This is actually something we’re working on at the moment that
> may be making an appearance in a future update.